# Database For Small Office

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, office365

Looking for some advice....I have a small office (3 people) and I want to setup a database to hold customers, invoices, appointment, billing, etc and be able to view and update the information.  What is the best/low cost way to go about this?  I wouldn't mind a cloud solution - since then I would know my data is backed up and available where ever I go.  I would need to be able to create queries to get reports and/or export files.
Thank you.

Comment: Postgres is never a bad choice. But you are not (only) looking for "a database", but also for an application/program that provides an UI where you can enter the data.

Comment: I am familiar with Access and SQL, so I could write my own front-ends in Access or SQL to create form for entries, updates, queries, etc.

Comment: Choose Cloud Platform since you would like a daily database backup,aws,google cloud,azure. database? postgresql +1.then you can hire a php guy to handle backend and front end.that is all.

Comment: So if we went with something like Google Cloud - do they have a database we can populate and pull data from?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas...I think we know where to go now.